# SQL - How to combine 2 dates from different tables with joins without error

Tags: sql, join, union, amazon-redshift

Im my company, there are 2 tables to carry the campaign information and the webshop information.

**Basic information**

In the campaign table it carries the information like as follows:

```
CAMPAIGN_NAME  CREATION_DATE  NUM_DELIVERED  NUM_ERRORS
Promotion 101   2013-01-05      100,000        100
Promotion 105   2013-01-05      135,000        200
Promotion 104   2013-01-05      125,000         0
Promotion 103   2013-01-06      50,000          0
```

In the webshop it carries the information like this

```
VISIT_KEY    VISIT_AT  .....
 100200     2013-01-05
 105235     2013-01-05
 103050     2013-01-05
```

**Desired outcome**

We want to build up a table to show the effect for each day like

```
CREATION_DATE    VISIT_AT   NUM_DELIVERED  NUM_VISITS
 2013-01-05     2013-01-05    260,000        30,000
 2013-01-06     2013-01-06     50,000          0
```

**Before and after approach**
to collect the information, before we were using the using the union method, which first do the aggregation in separate table and UNION ALL to another,

```
SELECT 
   campaign_date,
   visit_date,
   SUM(delivered),
   SUM(visits)
FROM
    ((Select
       CREATION_DATE::DATE as campaign_date,
       '1970-01-01'::DATE as visit_date
       SUM(NUM_DELIVERED) as delivered
       0 AS visits
    FROM 
       campaign
    GROUP BY 1,2)
    UNION ALL
    (Select
       '1970-01-01'::Date AS campaign_date,
       VISIT_AT::DATE AS visit_date
       0 AS delivered
       COUNT(VISIT_KEY) AS visits
    FROM 
       campaign
    GROUP BY 1,2))
 GROUP BY 1,2
```

which look like this

```
campaign_date visit_date   delivered      visits
2013-01-05    1970-01-01    260,000          0
1970-01-01    2013-01-05       0          30,000
2013-01-06    1970-01-01     50,000          0
```

Now I tried to combine with a left join on campaign.CREATION_DATE = webshop.VISIT_AT like this:

```
Select 
  campaign.CREATION_DATE as campaign_date, 
  webshop.VISIT_AT as visits,
  SUM(campaign.NUM_DELIVERED) as delivered,
  COUNT(webshop.VISIT_KEY) AS visits
FROM 
  webshop LEFT JOIN campaign ON webshop.VISIT_AT = campaign.CREATION_DATE
```

But the figure is totally different....

**Question**

1, What is the possible error in this query? Coz I am supposing to get the same information and the same result should be expected...

2, How can I achieve the desired outcome?

For your reference, I am using Amazon redshift.

Many thanks for your help in advance and have a nice weekend!

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please [edit] your query and add the query that produces the error.  [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Are you saying that each campaign runs a single day and that, at any day, there can be one and only one running campaign?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method uses `union all` and `group by`:

```
select dte, sum(num_delivered) as num_delivered, sum(num_visits) as num_visits
from ((select creation_date as dte, sum(num_delivered) as num_delivered, 0 as num_visits
       from campaign
       group by creation_date
      ) union all
      (select visit_at, 0 as num_delivered, sum(num_visits) as num_visits
       from webshop
       group by visit_at
      )
     ) cw
group by dte
order by dte;
```

I see no reason to have two date columns.

An alternative is a `full outer join` after aggregating:

```
select coalesce(creation_date, visit_at) as dte,
       coalesce(num_delivered, 0) as num_delivered, 
       coalesce(num_visits, 0) as num_visits
from (select creation_date, sum(num_delivered) as num_delivered, 0 as num_visits
      from campaign
      group by creation_date
     ) c full outer join
     (select visit_at, 0 as num_delivered, sum(num_visits) as num_visits
      from webshop
      group by visit_at
     ) 
     on w.visit_at = c.creation_dte
order by dte;
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution to your problem:

USING `DISTINCT`

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.Creation_Date, 
       c.Creation_Date AS Visit_At, 
       c.Num_Delivered, 
       c.Num_Visits
FROM (
      SELECT c.Creation_Date, 
             SUM(c.Num_Delivered) AS Num_Delivered, 
             SUM(c.Num_Errors) AS Num_Visits
      FROM Campaign AS c
      GROUP BY c.Creation_Date
     ) AS c
LEFT JOIN Webshop AS w
ON c.Creation_Date = w.Visit_At
```

**OR**

You can use `GROUP BY` Instead of `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT c.Creation_Date, c.Creation_Date AS Visit_At, c.Num_Delivered, c.Num_Visits
FROM (
      SELECT c.Creation_Date, SUM(c.Num_Delivered) AS Num_Delivered, SUM(c.Num_Errors) AS Num_Visits
      FROM Campaign AS c
      GROUP BY c.Creation_Date
     ) AS c
LEFT JOIN Webshop AS w
ON c.Creation_Date = w.Visit_At
GROUP BY c.Creation_Date, c.Creation_Date , c.Num_Delivered, c.Num_Visits
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Creation_Date   Visit_At     Num_Delivered  Num_Visits
2013-01-05      2013-01-05   360000          30000
2013-01-06      2013-01-06   50000           0
```

Link To the demo:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/22fe0/1